# When feeding 10 poor people as an expiation for breaking an oath (kaffarah yameen), does it have to be within the same day?

Tags: oaths, kaffarah

السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته

...Or can it be...

**a) spread out over 10 consecutive days?**

Example: feed 1 poor person today, then another one tomorrow, then 2 the next day...and so on until 10 are fed.

**b) spread out over 10 "non-consecutive" days?**

Example: feed 1 poor person today, then another one "the day after tomorrow", then 2 the next day, then 1 two days later...and so on until 10 are fed within, let's say, 1 month.

Please provide the source for your answer!

Jazak Allah khair!

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. For further information about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: Also see https://www.alifta.gov.sa/En/IftaContents/IbnBaz/Pages/default.aspx?cultStr=en&View=Page&PageID=4601&PageNo=1&BookID=14